# Clear list of user authorized browsers/ ip addresses after 30 days

Tags: apex, security, authentication

When user logs in a new browser (ip address) to Salesforce instance he's prompted to confirm his new device via email (authorization). Then all the info is stored as a list of activated client browsers (ip addresses).

What is the way to reset all data and prompt authorization again after 30 days?

We tried to set up 2fa but it forces to confirm via phone every 24 hours. There's no api / apex for activated client browsers so I can't create a batch process. I couldn't find any settings for clearing user sessions info. How would you strengthen the security?

Answer (score 0):

i believe clearing all the stored cache in the browser will prompt the user again for authorization...In that case we can create a command batch to clear all the cache in the browser...and schedule the batch file to run every 30 days..